# Lua Script - Attempt to index global (a nil value)

Tags: lua

If I am running this Code than I am getting the error that says:

```
imapfilter/config.lua:9: attempt to index global 'account1' (a nil value)
```

The Code [[Source]](http://www.michael-heck.net/index.php/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-als-imap-spamfilter) is below:

```
options.timeout = 120
options.subscribe = true

account1 = IMAP {
 server = 'mail.xxx.de',
 username = 'username',
 password = 'password',

 msgs = account1.INBOX:contain_subject('***SPAM***'),
 account1.INBOX:move_messages(account1['spam'],msgs)


}
```

The Commas are not correct?

Comment: My guess is that `}` should be after the line `password = 'password',` instead.

Comment: You're calling `account1` in its own definition. It doesn't exist until you close it out with `}`, so defining `msgs` can't refer to it.

Comment: Thanks guys.. You saved my day!

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan You should have just written that as an answer.

Comment: @Staven I usually only comment if I'm unsure I'm actually fixing the problem, and also this was a typographical error so I flagged it as off topic instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `account1` on it's own definition.
That's not possible 'cause `account1` doesn't exist until you close it with `}`